# Show query parameter in crystal report from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text, crystal-reports, query-string

I executed a query with parameters `DtpFrom.Text` & `DtpTo.Text`. I just need to display parameters on report in text object (`FromDate` & `ToDate`)

```
Dim rpt As New TrialBalance_ 'The report created.

    Try

        Dim comd As New OracleCommand("select Jv_acc_name, sum(debit) as debit, sum (CREDIT) as Credit from VOUCHER_DETAIL  GROUP BY jv_acc_name order by JV_ACC_NAME", sgcnn)

        comd.Parameters.Add("From", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DtpFrom.Text
        comd.Parameters.Add("To", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = DtpTo.Text

        Dim da As New OracleDataAdapter(comd)

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        da.Fill(dt)
        rpt.SetDataSource(dt)

        CrvTrialBalance.ReportSource = rpt
        rpt.Refresh()

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox(ex.Message)

    End Try
```

Please tell me what I need to do for this ......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create parameters DtpFrom, DtpTo in the Crystal Reports design.

Put them on the report where you want them to show up.

Pass the parameters via code:

```
  //supposing rpt is a ReportDocument
  rpt.SetParameterValue("DtpFrom", DtpFrom.Text);    
  rpt.SetParameterValue("DtpTo", DtpTo.Text);
```

Comment: heringer , I  get this msg "invaild Index msg (Exception HRESULT ..................)" what i do now ....?

Comment: i just need to print date as "text", reports parameters working fine in oracle command (comd) .... how i can print data from "forms controls to crystal report text object ?????

Comment: when i do this ...... rpt.SetParameterValue("DtpFrom", DtpFrom.Text)
            rpt.SetParameterValue("DtpTo", DtpTo.Text) .............. crystal report open window to enter parameter , i already entered parameter and its working fine i just need to "print" my parameters as "text"

Comment: When you created the parameters in Cystal Reports design, did you set their types to Data? If so, try to change the types to string and see what happens.

Comment: I did, but result is same

Comment: Are you sure DtpFrom.Text and DtpTo.Text have values? May you post a screenshot of your rpt design showing the parameters fields and where you put them? May you edit your post and include the new code with the SetParameterValue calls?